# Do psionics powers' effects stack?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, psionics, stacking

If an Elan Aegis obtains the Unlocked Talent and Access Psionics Powers, can they stack fortify, lesser +1 and fortify +2 and Resistance (due to Elan) +4 on saving throws (spending Power points)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Psionic powers stack in exactly the same ways as magic spells: typed bonuses do not stack with other bonuses of the same type,<sup>1</sup> and untyped bonuses do not stack when applied repeatedly by the same effect.

*Fortify* and *lesser fortify* both supply resistance bonuses to saving throws. Since both bonuses are “resistance bonuses,” they do not stack. They also don’t stack with the *resistance* spell, or with a *cloak of resistance*, since those also supply “resistance bonuses.”

The elan’s resistance ability, despite the name, does not supply a “resistance bonus.” Instead, it is a “racial bonus.” This does stack with *fortify* or *lesser fortify* (or *resistance* or a *cloak of resistance*), so you could get +5 or +6 that way. And, per <sup>1</sup>, racial bonuses stack with themselves, the resistance ability will stack with almost everything—the only thing it won’t stack with is itself, so you can’t use it twice<sup>2</sup> to get a +8 bonus.

1. <sub>Unless they are circumstance bonuses, dodge bonuses, or racial bonuses.</sub>
2. <sub>It is possible to use the elan’s resistance ability twice before the first expires, by using it once on your turn, as a swift action, and then again after your turn ends, as an immediate action. There is no benefit for doing so, since it is a supernatural ability and therefore cannot be dispelled.</sub>